# OpenID Connect ASP NET MVC AAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I implemented a sample app using OpenID Connect standard with ASP NET MVC website. My goal was to outsource storing sensitive data to Azure so i used Azure Active Directory. Since it's impossible to add custom properties to users in Azure i store non sensitive user Claims in our private db. I managed to get this claims and "add" them to the cookie like this:

```
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var objectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
                        var claims = GetUserClaims(objectId.Value);
                        foreach (var item in claims)
                        {
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(item.Key, item.Value));
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
```

This way I added required claims to the cookie so those claims persist in my User object until user sign-out which is fine but there is one Claim which can change during the session ( basically user can change it on one page ). The problem is I can't find how to "change" this Claim in the cookie so it will persist. Ideally I would like to somehow force

> AuthorizationCodeReceived

function to be called again. Is it possible ? Or is there another way where I can swap the value stored in the cookie ?

So far my only solution is to log-out user when he change this value so it will force him to sign-out again and my callback for AuthorizationCodeReceived will be called again, but it's not a very user-friendly way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn() after you add a claim in identity object to persist the new claim in cookie.

Comment: Will try and let you know.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work it didn't call the AuthorizationCodeReceived but this worked:             HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

Comment: Ammend your answer with my code and i'll mark it as done. Someone can find it usefull :)

Comment: @MajkeloDev good to know that you were able to solve the issue. The Challange() method may not necessarily invoke AuthorizationCodeReceived (when the request already has valid ID token) and it should only be invoke when you retrieving new token or renewing token from Identity provider i.e. AAD. It would be advisable that you should not depend on invoking AuthorizationCodeReceived. You can create a common method to refresh claims call it from AuthorizationCodeReceived or anywhere you need.

Comment: the reason why i do it in "AuthorizationCodeReceived" is that if I do it in different place ... I can't update the cookie so the claims I add to the user are not persisting :(